# What is free will skeptic stance on will and morality?

Tags: free-will

Before I try to give a definition of will, I will first present some statements and an argument for them.

1. Will is not free.
2. Will is separate from external forces.
3. Will is separate from transient cravings.
4. Will is separate from actions.

Argument for 1. Since everything in the world is entirely guided by laws of physics and will is a property of the physical brain, it is not free.

Argument for 2. Suppose Mark regularly checks his car for defects. Nevertheless, last time brakes have failed in his car and he has got into a car accident. By a common conculsion, this car accident was not a result of Mark's will.

Argument for 3. Suppose Jane tries to lose weight. Nevertheless, last night she ate a big piece of cake and now regrets it. Jane's regret shows that her will is to lose weight, not eat the piece of cake. A common conclusion would be that she is just weak-willed.

Argument for 4. Suppose Mary seeks to cure her sick husband. Victor, who for some reason wishes her husband to die but never shows it in public, offers her a "medicine" which in fact would be lethal. Mary gives that "medicine" to her husband and next day he dies. Despite Mary's actions, by a common conclusion, his death was not a result of Mary's will (but was a result of Victor's will).

There are some other examples of actions that would commonly be seen as not willed, e.g. when one was sleeping or their drink was spiked. It also is possible to present an argument for limited will, e.g. when bandits demand you give them your possessions of they will shoot you. In this case, you don't really wish to give them your possessions, you just value your life more.

Therefore, a reasonable conclusion would be that will stands for personal long term goals, and any agent who has will must have an ability for long term planning/dreaming.

From this it follows that willed undesirable actions (e.g. crimes) come from decisions related to long term goals. E.g. a recidivist robber trying to become rich willfully robs. Meanwhile an old starving man stealing food follows his survival instincts, not long term goals. Maybe this is, at least in part, why so many people would think the robber is more blameworthy than the old man?

It still, however, does not follow that the robber has free will: propensity for robbing would just be a part of his "nature" and we'd need to imprison him not in order to "teach him a lesson," but to prevent further crimes that would imminently follow otherwise, since, again, it's in his "nature" to rob (at least until he feels rich).

However, my question then is, how do these views relate to the views of free will skeptics, compatibilists and libertarians? For example, do compatibilists call "free will" just what I call will or is their position different? Do libertarians believe that the robber can just suddenly change without any external cause? And if so, why would they insist on a punishment?

Comment: This is a thinly-disguised "am I right" question.

Comment: I am asking about how this relates to other positions, not whether I am right. As in, for example, do compatibilists call "free will" just what I call will or is their position different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are subtleties to all three views, that your 4 questions are actually useful for sorting out.

For 1) SOME free will skeptics argue for reductive determinism.  But others -- agree that physics is not determinist, because it includes probabilistic phenomenon. Free will is not compatible with a merely probabilistic physics either.  Free will skepticism is most strongly argued for based on a logic argument -- that all things in our universe are either deterministically caused OR statistically "caused". And neither is compatible with free will.

For compatibilists, they generally accept emergence, and that mind exists.  Most are physicalists too, with an at least moderate, or sometimes strong emergence assumed.  "Free Will" is redefined as causation that runs thru our minds, where the reduction of our minds to physics is TBD, and may not be true (most compatibilists are non-reductive physicalists).  Compatibilists distinguish between mental choices, and when external uncontrolled world events interferes in mental willing.  Most emergent physicalism faces a problem that causation needs to be redefined to allow for parallel causation paths.

For libertarian free will, generally strong emergence, or spiritual dualism is needed, to allow for causation in the mental to not go thru physics.  This also needs our understand of causation to be expanded to determined, random, AND agent causation.

For 2) Free will skeptics disagree. If one can reduce all causation to physics, including emergent physical phenomenon, then willing, as an outcome of emergence, is no more separate from external forces than the brakes failing.

Compatibilists basically say that our inability to reduce mental to the physical is a current issue, and whether we can resolve that or not is a possible future investigation project.  But pragmatically, we should distinguish between internal mental events and external events, as our mental is effectively causal, and we know we can influence it internally, and changing mental attitudes can have major effects on our behavior.  Distinguishing mental causation from external causation is a useful pragmatic distinguishment.

Libertarian free will agrees with your 2).

For 3) Free will skeptics disagree based on 2).

Compatibilists generally agree, and consider the psychological ability to overcome the attraction of transient cravings in favor of long term thinking to be an important goal of psychological maturation.  Compatibilists and libertarian free will advocates then to be in sync on 3).

For 4), free will skeptics once more deny this point, as they say there is no free will.

Compatibilists generally agree with your point 4, willing is what we mentally try to achieve.   But eating the cake was also willed.  Libertarian free will advocates would agree on that last point too.

For punishment, none of the three views strongly encourages it.  In both compatibilism and libertarian free will, the goal of socialization is to strengthen our ability to behave morally and with long-term thinking.  Punishment is an inefficient way to do this, and the way our criminal justice system works is often ineffective.

Our human inclination toward punishment, can best be seen as a psychological "craving" we developed from evolutionarily developing our psychologies in a lawless world, where hurting those who hurt you is a useful disincentive to fellow tribe members engaging in theft or abuse or other violations of tribal norms.  Resisting this craving is supported by all three views.

Libertarian free will advocates DO believe a robber can just change their attitudes based on internal thinking. But moral suasion also helps a lot for internal thinking, and providing or appealing to an inner moral framework would be the best way to do this.

Comment: "If one can reduce all causation to physics, including emergent physical phenomenon, then willing, as an outcome of emergence, is no more separate from external forces than the brakes failing." That actually sounds reductive. Reductive in the same manner as "Both the brain and the heart consist of cells, therefore they are not different." Of course, in this case I have defined "Will" in a colloquial manner, not as "Free will."

Comment: @rus9384 -- Many free will skeptics are reductionists.  Reductionism leads to free will skepticism.  it is not a 1:1 relationship, but reductionists tend to be free will skeptics, and emergent physicalists tend to be compatibilists.

Comment: So, I guess, compatibilist "free will" is equivalent to colloquial "will" (associated with willpower).

Comment: @rus9384 Most standard usage is libertarian.  Compatibilists redefine "free" and "agency" from standard usage.  "Will" ends up being pretty close to standard usage in compatibilism, but is seen as self-trainable inclinations, rather than acts of moral forcefulness, or personal willpower.  Free Will skeptics tend to be Utilitarians. 
 But Compatibilists can embrace Virtue Ethics, as their fellow compatibilists, the Stoics were key in developing Virtues theory.

Answer (score 1):

Free will skeptics usually say that if we do not have free will, then we cannot be held morally responsible for our actions. This is because moral responsibility requires that we have the ability to choose between right and wrong. If our choices are determined by prior causes, then we do not have this ability.

But I kinda do not see what exactly you are asking. Looks you have a lot of statements and examples but your actual question is a bit vague in the end.